# access an image in cgi-bin

Tags: image, perl, relative-path, cgi-bin

I have a quick question regarding my assignment for school. So essentially it is a webform and I upload a photo and some info, and the .cgi file populates the data into a profile. I got it working when I upload the image to "public_html/images" folder, however the assignment requires me to upload and retrieve the image from "public_html/cgi-bin/assn1/images". The image uploads to both the "public_html/images" and the "../cgi-bin/assn1/images". However, in the case of the latter, I can't retrieve it. Can someone please give me some information as to how I could go about doing this? Also this is the school server so I am limited to what I can do...

```
profile photo.... <img src="../assn1/images/$fileName">
```

Any help would be appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Cheers

Comment: If you verified it is uploaded in both places, then my guess is that the path is incorrect. Maybe try using the full path from your root html directory. `/cgi-bin/assn1/images`

Comment: So I tried that... and the image still doesn't come up. So when I right click on the broken image link and select "copy image location" I get http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/cgi-bin/assn1/images/successkid.jpeg. Which is incorrect. Since .cgi file is in http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~int322_143sa15/cgi-bin/assn1/viewprofile.cgi and as I mentioned above, my images folder is inside assn1

Comment: Update it to the correct path that matches your system. In your second link, the image source is `<img src="/~int322_143sa15/images/">` which is a directory, not an image. Fix your code so that it outputs the path you expect, which I think is something like `http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~int322_143sa15/cgi-bin/assn1/images/$fileName` based on the info you gave. But I cant be sure since theres not enough information

Answer (score 0):

What, exactly, do you mean by "I can't retrieve it"? Are you getting some kind of error message or a missing image icon? Is anything being written to the web server error log?

It's possible that the web server is configured so that everything under the /cgi-bin directory is interpreted as a CGI program. In which case, you shouldn't be storing static content there.